# Set-DnsClientGlobalSetting - throwing "Access to a CIM resource was not available"

Tags: active-directory, windows-10, internal-dns

I am trying to add a Suffix to list of existing domains on my workstation but am getting the error below. It persist despite running PowerShell as an administrator. I have domains ABC and DEF in the list and want to add xyz.

```
Set-DnsClientGlobalSetting -SuffixSearchList @("abc.com", "def.com", "xyz.com")
```

Edit: This is the full error.

```
 Set-DnsClientGlobalSetting : Access to a CIM resource was not available to the client.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-DnsClientGlobalSetting -SuffixSearchList @("abc.com", " ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (MSFT_DNSClientG...nstanceID = ""):ROOT/StandardCi...ntGlobalSetting) [Set-DnsClientGlobalSetting], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 2,Set-DnsClientGlobalSetting
```

Comment: What is the real error? The one you listed is just the global error, not the detailed message (CategoryInfo). Usually this is due to denied permissions.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is because you have a GPO defining the DNS suffix search list.

I was able to validate this in my environment by having a computer in a test OU and test GPO assigned to it with the `DNS suffix search list` setting disabled. Make sure this test GPO takes precedence over other GPOs that may define the DNS suffix search list.

After ensuring a GPO wasn't defining the DNS suffix search list, this command should as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was just having a similar issue with a similar error message. Please, try to run PowerShell as an administrator. This may fix your permission issue.